# When Flashing a ROM should I back up Google Apps?

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing, titanium-backup

My ROM distributor (Unofficial CM10) provides GAPPS as a separate flashable zip file. Will my titanium back'd up Google apps interfere/replace with the GAPPS provided after I restore my backup ?

Answer (score 4):

If it is gmail, then these are in data and titanium fully supports them.

Google play is a system package, and as are many other gapps. You must flash them using the zip provided, but you can use titanium to restore their data, although all the data is backed up online.

Comment: Keep in mind to not restore system *apps*, just their data, when switching ROMs. Also make sure to enable TBs migration feature to avoid trouble.

Answer (score 0):

**EVERYTHING** should be backed up. You are never enough careful when you do such manipulations.